# Can C# Nullable<T> types preserve information about internal type after MakeByRefType?

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, pass-by-reference, system.reflection

I'm trying to create an instance of an object with a private (or rather, internal) constructor using reflection:

```
internal static T CreateInstance<T>(Type[] types, params object[] args)
{
    var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, types, null);
    if (ctor != null) 
        return (T) ctor.Invoke(args);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No constructor available with specified argument types to reflect.");
```

This code works for most cases, but fails for the following constructor (from the VulkanCore library):

`internal SurfaceKhr(Instance parent, ref AllocationCallbacks? allocator, long handle)`

This represents itself, if you list the ParameterInfo objects for the constructor:

`` parent, VulkanCore.Instance, allocator, System.Nullable`1[VulkanCore.AllocationCallbacks]&, handle, System.Int64 ``

However, if you check the type information of: `new []{typeof(Instance), typeof(Nullable<AllocationCallbacks>).MakeByRefType(), typeof(Int64)}` for `types`, it yields: `` Instance, Nullable`1&, Int64 ``. This is the same output when checking the equivalent type: `typeof(AllocationCallbacks?).MakeByRefType()`.

Is there any way to preserve the internal class of `ref AllocationCallbacks?` for use when looking for the constructor via `typeof(T).GetConstructor(...)`?

Comment: This is a `ToString()` problem -- the information is still in there.

Comment: @BenVoigt entirely possible, but that doesn't help, considering it's not actually finding the constructor.

Comment: @Pip Then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can not reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lo5SjH